# Android Espresso does not work properly

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am digging for more than one week for an android tests with espresso.
I can not make Idle resourses work properly in my project (integrate into project).
Here is what I added to build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    // Testing-only dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
}

testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

What is in test class:

```
    SetUp:
countingResource = new CountingIdlingResource("HelloWorldServerCalls");
Espresso.registerIdlingResources(countingResource);
```

In Test method:

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.btnLogIn)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));
        Log.d(TAG, "We are in WalkthroughActivity, user is not logged in");

//press button  - walk to next activity
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.btnLogIn)).perform(ViewActions.click());

//register MyUserHelperV2 - this is Server decorator
 final LoginActivity act = (LoginActivity) getCurrentActivity();
        LoginActivity.Server aHelper = act.getUserHelper();
        MyUserHelperV2 helper = new MyUserHelperV2(aHelper, countingResource);
        act.setUserHelper(helper);

    //set password and email
  Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.email)).perform(ViewActions.typeText("test@mail.ru"));
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.password)).perform(ViewActions.typeText("password111"));
         //Check if button R.id.btnLogInApp exists: 
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.btnLogInApp)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));

Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard();
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.btnLogInApp)).perform(ViewActions.click());
    //in last line we have PerformException - can not find R.id.btnLogInApp,
```

But for sure this button exist - I can emulate not-idle(sync) call and all is working OK.
I am thinking I can make a mistake in settings - on android 5 all works, on other androids <5 - does not.

I have dug through a lot of samples, and for sure implemented Idle res perfectly. But I am too bad with gradle system.
Please help, I am desperate with espresso and gradle, I can attach more spec code if needed.

Comment: can you please post what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a build.gradle example file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion "22"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.awesome.app"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22.0.1
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
}

dependencies {
// App's dependencies, including test
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'

// Testing-only dependencies
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
```

And a test class exemple

Android Studio create test by default in src/androidTest/java/com.example.package/

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
 public class HelloWorldEspressoTest {

@Rule
 public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class);

@Test
 public void listGoesOverTheFold() {
    onView(withText("Hello world!")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
 }
}
```